# Double Sum, taking a constant out of the first sum gives a different result

Tags: replacement, summation, order

I have a code with the following double sum:

```
Sum[Sum[(-1-k+f[k]) (-l+n+f[l]), {l,k+1,n}], {k,1,n}] /. f[r_] -> If[r == 1, n, 0]
```

With that, I get:

[image: Result]

I wanted to simplify the expression by taking the term independent from l out of the first sum like this:

```
Sum[(-1-k+f[k]) Sum[(-l+n+f[l]),{l,k+1,n}], {k,1,n}] /. f[r_] -> If[r == 1, n, 0]
```

But I get a different result:

[image: Result 2]

I can't seem to figure out why. I'm quite stuck with this problem, please if you have any suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I would try giving `n` a small value and see which answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Your function `f` is just

```
f[r_] := n*KroneckerDelta[r, 1];

f[r] == If[r == 1, n, 0] // PiecewiseExpand

(* True *)

sum1 = Sum[Sum[(-1 - k + f[k]) (-l + n + f[l]), {l, k + 1, n}], {k, 1, n}]
```

[image]

Note that this double `Sum` can be written more succinctly as

```
sum1s = Sum[(-1 - k + f[k]) (-l + n + f[l]), {k, 1, n}, {l, k + 1, n}]
```

[image]

As expected, the results are identical

```
sum1 === sum1s

(* True *)
```

As you showed, immediate evaluation of your second double `Sum` gives

```
sum2 = Sum[(-1 - k + f[k]) Sum[(-l + n + f[l]), {l, k + 1, n}], {k, 1, n}]
```

[image]

Define the double `Sum` to only evaluate with known values of `n` (delayed evaluation)

```
sum2d[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Sum[(-1 - k + f[k]) Sum[(-l + n + f[l]), {l, k + 1, n}], {k, 1, n}]
```

Comparing the results for specific values of `n`

```
Table[sum1, {n, 1, 10}]

(* {0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 0, -14, -42, -90} *)

Table[sum2, {n, 1, 10}]

(* {0, -3, -11, -27, -55, -100, -168, -266, -402, -585} *)

Table[sum2d[n], {n, 1, 10}]

(* {0, 0, 1, 3, 5, 5, 0, -14, -42, -90} *)
```

The second double `Sum` evaluates correctly if evaluation is delayed until `n` is known.